# The function runtime is unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus: Value for the connection string parameter name '@Microsoft.KeyVault

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, serverless, azure-keyvault

I have an Azure Function with a `ServiceBusTrigger` in it. Now I have set the value of `ServiceBusConnectionString` in application settings. I am basically taking the connection string value from the `Azure KeyVault`. But I am always getting an error as below, whenever I run my Azure Function after I did this changes. Any help is really appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Why bother using KV if you're going to put the plaintext secret in App Settings?
The app should read the secret from KV at start.

Comment: The point is that app settings are all stored in one place and can be re-used across multiple services - I do the same myself. Once the new app settings service is out of preview then I'd agree with you, but until then this is a setup I use myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fount out what was causing this issue. Apparently there was a typo in the App Settings value. I was missing the `SecretUri=` in the value. So, instead of `@Microsoft.KeyVault(Secret URI with version)`, we should use `@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=Secret URI with version)`.

[image]

So after doing that changes, the error was gone. Hope it helps.